# GLSL fragment shader not handling alpha channel

Tags: opengl, glsl, gradient, fragment-shader, alphablending

I am trying to make a few simple gradient fragment shaders for a program. Nothing fancy just specify a start and stop color and interpolate between the two. Everything seem to work fine except for the alpha channel. It seems like unless the color is clear black (black with an alpha of 0) the alpha channel is either ignored or gets set to 1.

[Input colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umpww.png)

[What I expect to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXNlq.png)

[What I actually see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt6cq.png)

**Fragment Shader:**

```
uniform mediump vec4 TopColor;
uniform mediump vec4 BottomColor;
uniform mediump float ViewHeight;
uniform mediump vec4 kzViewport;

void main()
{
    precision mediump float;

    float centerY = ViewHeight / 2.0;
    float r = abs(gl_FragCoord.y - centerY) / centerY;

    gl_FragColor = mix(TopColor, BottomColor, r);
}
```

**Vertex Shader:**

```
attribute vec3 kzPosition;
uniform highp mat4 kzProjectionCameraWorldMatrix;
void main()
{
    precision mediump float;
    gl_Position = kzProjectionCameraWorldMatrix * vec4(kzPosition.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: If you say the colors are interpolated correctly, then there is nothing wrong with the shader. Maybe you forgot to enable blending in your engine, or something similar?

Comment: Surely you have forgot to set ```glEnable(GL_BLEND);
 glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);```

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I would consider not honoring the change in alpha something "wrong" but yea the problem might not be with the shader itself.

Comment: I mean, your shader handles RGB and A components in a completely same way. So there is no way A output is incorrect is RGB output is correct at the same time.

Comment: do you even have Alpha BUFFER in your pixel format? If not setting blending will not help